# How to turn on LED after RPi booting is done

Tags: gpio, boot, led

I would like to know if RPi booting is done without connecting to the monitor.
So, I would like to use LED connected to the GPIO to know it.
What code should I write?

Comment: Do you have your LED working with your GPIO already or do you need help with that also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cron` is  one way to do it, just set the "time" to `@reboot`.

Another way is with your startup system, which for Raspbian Wheezy is `upstart`. You can see [this page](http://www.mikeslab.net/?p=176) on how to set it up. Basically, you need your LED to be activated by a bash script (this usually involves setting the appropriate GPIO pin high). Once you have that script, it's a simple matter of registering it with `upstart` using the `update-rc.d` command.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'm using Raspbian Wheezy. Could you give me more specific explanations?

Comment: @S.W.Hong Updated my answer to reflect Wheezy startup.